# Require authorization to access ec2 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Not sure what the right terms were to start this question but basically I have a downloaded UI tool that runs on 0.0.0.0:5000 on my AWS EC2 instance and my ec2 instance has a public ip address associated with it.  So right now everyone in the world can access this tool by going to {ec2_public_ip}:5000.

I want to run some kinda script or add security group inbound rules that will require authorization prior to letting someone view the page.  The application running on port 5000 is a downloaded tool not my own code so it wouldnt be possible to add authentication to the tool itself (Its KafkaMagic FYI).

The one security measure I was able to do so far was only allow specific IPs TCP connection to port 5000, which is a good start but not enough as there is no guarantee someone on that IP is authorized to view the tool.  Is it possible to require an IAM role to access the IP?  I do have a separate api with a login endpoint that could be useful if it was possible to run a script before forwarding the request, is that a possible/viable solution?  Not sure what best practice is in this case, there might be a third option I have not considered.

**ADD-ON EDIT**
Additionally, I am using EC2 Instance Connect and if it is possible to require an active ssh connection before accessing the ec2 instances ip that would be a good solution as well.

**EDIT FOLLOWING INITIAL DISCUSSION**

Another approach that would work for me is if I had a small app running on a different port that could leverage our existing UI to log a user in.  If a user authenticated through this app, would it be possible to display the ui from port 5000 to them then?  In this case KafkaMagic would be on a private ip and there would be a different IP that the user would go through before seeing the tool

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer is *no*. If you want authorization (I think, you mean, authentication) to access an application running on the server - you need tools that run *on the server*. If your tool offers such capability - use it. It looks like Kafka Magic *has* such capability: https://www.kafkamagic.com/faq/#how-to-authenticate-kafka-client-by-consumer-group-id

But you can't use external tools, like AWS, that perform such authentication. Security group is like a firewall - it either allows or blocks access to the port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it seems that the public ip would have a firewall and then all traffic would still get to the site and I could add consumer group authentication here.  

Another use case that would work for me is if I had a small login tool running on a different port and once the user logged in I display the kafka magic tool.  Im gonna add that to the original question since I dont believe it was clear.

Comment: that would be a Kafka question; not AWS. Some applications allow easy setup of proxy server; others make it very difficult. I am not familiar with Kafka

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a script that uses the aws sdk or even just executes the aws CLI to view/add/remove an ip address of a security group. How you execute that script depends on your audience and what language you use.

For a small number of trusted users you could issue them an IAM user and API key with a policy that allows them to manage a single dynamic security group. Then provide a script they can run/shortcut to click that gets the current gateway ip and adds/removes it from the security group.

If you want to allow users via website a simple script behind some existing authentication is also possible with sdk/cli approach(depending on available server side scripting).

If users have SSH access - you could authorise the ip by calling the script/cli from bashrc or some other startup script.

In any case the IAM policy that grants permissions to modify the SG should be as restrictive as possible (basically dont use any `*`'s in the policy). You can add additional conditions like the source IP/range (ie in your VPC) or that MFA must be active for user etc to make this more secure (can be handled in either case via script). If your running on ec2 id suggest looking at IAM Instance Roles as an easy way to give your server access to credentials for your script (but you can create a user and deploy the key/secret to the server and manage it manually if you wanted).

I would also suggest creating a dedicated security group for dynamically managed access alongside existing SGs required for internal operation for safety. It would be a good idea to implement a lambda function on a schedule to flush the dynamic SG (even if you script de-authorising an IP it might not happen so its good to clean up safely/automatically).